# If I backup my Ubuntu (unity) using Deja, can I restore it when I use a fresh install of UbuntuGNOME?

Tags: unity, gnome, deja-dup

This may be a weird question, but it has me stumped and google is little help. I am currently running Ubuntu with the default Unity interface. I've been wanting to experiment with different DE's for a while now and have finally been convinced to just use UbuntuGNOME instead of juggling Unity and Gnome as this has caused issues in the past. My question is, if I'm backing up my system now using the default backup app Deja Dup (on Unity), can I restore it once I have UbuntuGNOME (simply so I can get my personal files back from my home folder- music, pics, etc.) or do I have to back those files up independently of the backup files because of compatibility issues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've got space somewhere to make an independent backup, then you should probably do it.  Having an extra backup available will not hurt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Deja Dup uses [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) as its backend.

It's desktop agnostic; duplicity doesn't care what desktop you use.